# finding the cardinality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]
I was trying to show the complementary set is finite .I got the complenentary set as $\{ k\in \mathbb{N}: P_{k+1} - p_k=2 \}$. Don't know know how to show the set is finite. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody knows if the complementary set is finite or not! Presumably it is, in fact, infinite. That's the so-called twin-prime conjecture.

Comment: Hint:  if $p_{k+1}=p_k+2$ show that $p_{k+2}-p_{k+1}>2$ (at least for large enough $k$).

Comment: Advise:  The text put it in terms of $k$, the index.  That's weird and could be very confusing to a math novice.  I'd suggest not thinking in terms of the $k$ but in terms of the primes.  In other words:  Prove there are an infinite number of primes where either $p + 2$ or $p-2$ are not prime.  That is the same thing.  But it's much clearer what the are asking that way.

Comment: Oh... I should have read the hint from lulu.  Correct and perfect as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the numbers
$$n!+2,n!+3,\ldots,n!+n $$
for an arbitrary positive integer $n$. These numbers are all composite and successive. So you can by considering $n$ big enough, there is index $k$ in which $p_{k+1}-p_k>n-1>2$. By changing $n$ infinitely many times, we reach the desired quest.

Comment: Simpler.  If $p\ne 3$ is prime then either $p+2$ or $p-2$ is divisible by three.  So if $p = p_k > 5$ then either $p_k +2 \ne p_{k+1}$ or $p_k - 2 \ne p_{k-1}$.  (Obviously $p_k \pm 1$ are not prime.)

Comment: $p=17$ then $p+2=19$?

Comment: .... and $p - 2 = 15$.  So for $p_7$ we have $p_7 + 2 = p_8$ but we do not have $p_7 - 2 = p_6$.   For any $p_k$ either $p_k + 2 \ne p_{k+1}$ or $p_k - 2 \ne p_{k-1}$ because one of $p_k \pm 2$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I'm afraid to say you just proved the " twin primes conjecture"! I

Comment: What?  How?  I said either $p+2$ or $p-2$ is not prime.  I never said it was an exclusive or.  Obiviously say $p = 23$ we have $p-2=21$ is divisible by $3$ and $p + 2=25$ is not divisible by $3$.  That doesn't mean it isn't divisible by anything else.

Comment: I mean you proved that the number of twin primes are finite!

Comment: How?  I have proven that there is only one prime triplet $(3,5,7)$ and that in any other triplet $(k-2,k,k+2)$ and least one is divisible by $3$ and not prime. But there is nothing about twins being finite.  If  $(k, k+2)$  ($k>5$) are a twin prime then I have proven $(k-2,k)$ are not a twin prime.  But nothing in that says twin primes are finite.

Comment: Where is my error?  If $p$ is prime greater than 5 then $p \not \equiv 0 \mod 3$ so $p\equiv \pm 1 \mod 3$. If $p\equiv 1\mod 3$then $p+2\equiv 1+2\equiv 0 \mod 3$.  If $p\equiv -1 \mod 3$ then $p-3\equiv -1-2\equiv 0 \mod 3$ so either $p+2$ is divisible by 3 or $p-2$ is divisible by 3.  So there are an infinite number of primes were either $p_k + 2\ne p_{k+1}$ or $p_{k-1}+2\ne p_k$.  So either $p_{k} - p_{k-1} > 2$ or $p_{k+1} - p_k > 2$.  Which proves the problem and says *nothing* about twin primes (except that *non* twins are not finite ... which... well, duh.)

Comment: I deal with you. I was wrong.

Comment: I think the proof uses the fact the number of primes us infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma:  Given the three numbers $k-2$ and $k$ and $k+2$ exactly one of them is divisible by $3$.

Pf:  Let $r$ be the remainder when you divide $k$ by $3$.  Either $r = 0, 1,$ or $2$.  There are no other options.  If $r=0$ then $k = 3m$ for some integer $m$ and $k$ is divisible by $3$. If $r = 1$ then $k = 3m + 1$ for some integer $m$ and $k +2 = 3m + 3 = 3(m+1)$ and $k+2$ is divisible by $3$.  If $r=2$ then $k = 3m +2$  for some integer $m$ and $k -2 = 3m$ and $k-2$ is divisible by $3$.

Do you see how that lemma means that there have to be an infinite number of $k$ where $p_{k+1} - p_k > 2$?  Try to think it out.

=====

> I was trying to show the complementary set is finite.

It's possible that both sets are infinite.

If I asked you to prove there were an infinite number of even numbers, it would be a bad idea for you to try to prove that there are finite number of odd numbers.  Yes, if there are a finite number of odd numbers then the compliment must be infinite.  But if a set is infinite it does not mean the compliment is finite.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.will u explain little nore why the lemma implies the proof ..I am stuch at that part..Lemma is easy.

Comment: for prime $p_k > 5$, it is not possible for $p_k -2, p_k,$ and $p_k + 2$ to all three be primes because one of them must be divisible by $3$.  So it is not possible for $p_{k-1} = p_k -2$ *AND* for $p_{k+1} = p_k + 2$ so either $p_{k-1} < p_k -1$ or$p_{k+1} > p_k + 2$.  So either $p_{k} - p_{k-1} > 2$ or $p_{k+1} - p_k > 2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help.